# QueryException, ErrorException and PDOException in Connection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to ask if you can help me with the errors I am encountering with my newly installed Laravel 5.4. Here is my blade template

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content') <div class="container">
<div class="row">                           
            {{ App\StudentHistory::select(['date', 'student_id', 'grade'])
            ->where('subject', 'English')
            ->groupBy('student_id')
            ->orderBy('date','desc')
            ->first()
            ->get()}}
    </div>@endsection
```

Let me know what else you guys need, I'll update as you ask

Comment: Why would you do a db query in your view layer?

Comment: There is no `->get()` on `->first()`

Comment: @Maerlyn, well I can actually do it from the controller. It's supposed to work both ways, right? Alex, you mean to say I can't have the two in the same syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're trying to run a db query in your view, which is better suited in your controller.
- You can't use first() and get() together, use one.
- You're trying to output the query result directly, which is an object, which would throw an error even if your query was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing xxx->first()->get() ...

You either call ->first() and get one object or do ->get() and get an array of objects

Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

PS: I really can't see the advantages of doing those queries IN the view, that's missing the MVC objective of laravel.

Comment: it's actually saying this in the PDOException "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause"...Does that relate?